How to Align Text Consistently Across Views Without Hidden Elements?
In my SwiftUI app, I have two views (FirstOnboardingView and SecondOnboardingView). In the first view, the text is positioned between a Circle and a Rectangle. In the second view, I want only the text to appear, but I need it to maintain the same position as in the first view.
Currently, I use hidden Circle and Rectangle elements in the second view to preserve alignment, but this feels like a hack. Is there a better way to achieve consistent alignment without using hidden elements or placeholders? Would matchedGeometryEffect or any other technique help here?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showSecondView: Bool = Bool()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            if (!showSecondView) {
                FirstOnboardingView()
            }
            else {
                SecondOnboardingView()
            }

            Button("update") {
                showSecondView.toggle()
            }

        }
        .padding()

    }

}

struct FirstOnboardingView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)

        Text("Hello, world!").font(.title.bold())

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 300.0)

    }

}



struct SecondOnboardingView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Circle()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
            .hidden()

        Text("I love SwiftUI!").font(.title.bold())

        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 300.0)
            .hidden()

    }

}


You don't need to give styling to the hidden elements - the colors can be dropped.

Using .hidden() is a perfectly valid technique and particularly useful for views with an unknown size.
The placeholder views only need to be the minimum necessary to establish their size. So styling that doesn't impact the size (like colors) can be dropped.
In your example, the placeholder views actually have a fixed size. So in this case, you could just use padding for the second onboarding view:

To control the spacing between elements, add a VStack with fixed spacing to the first view:

// FirstOnboardingView

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        // content as before
    }
}


The second onboarding view now reduces to the following:

// SecondOnboardingView

var body: some View {
    Text("I love SwiftUI!")
        .font(.title.bold())
        .padding(.top, 100 + 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 300 + 10)
}


Your approach is not a hack at all. This is what .hidden() is designed to do in the first place.
(Emphasis mine)

Hidden views are invisible and can’t receive or respond to interactions. However, they do remain in the view hierarchy and affect layout. Use this modifier if you want to include a view for layout purposes, but don’t want it to display.

Even if you use matchedGeometryEffect, the source view (that every other view matches) of the effect needs to be in the view hierarchy, so it needs to be hidden anyway.
As a proof of concept, this is how you would do it with matchedGeometryEffect,
@Namespace var ns
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        // this VStack acts as the source of the effect
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
            
            Text("Hello, world!").font(.title.bold())
                // isSource: true by default
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: ns)
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100.0, height: 300.0)
        }
        .hidden()
        
        // this is the actual VStack displaying the views
        VStack {
            if !showSecondView {
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
                
                Text("Hello, world!").font(.title.bold())
                    // we only want to match the position, not size, or else longer text will be truncated
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: ns, properties: .position, isSource: false)
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100.0, height: 300.0)
            } else {
                
                Text("I love SwiftUI!").font(.title.bold())
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 0, in: ns, properties: .position, isSource: false)
            }

            Button("update") {
                showSecondView.toggle()
            }

        }
    }
    .padding()
}

Another problem with matchedGeometryEffect is that it's only a visual effect. The "logical" frame (which SwiftUI uses to do other layout) of the "I love SwiftUI!" text is not changed by matchedGeometryEffect. For example, the position of the "update" button will be higher in the second view, compared to the first view, because the VStack has a shorter height. This may or may not be desirable.
